# Multiplying an array by a designated row vector of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Good afternoon all relatively simple`question here from a mechanical standpoint.

I'm currently performing PCA and have successfully written a code that computes the covariance matrix and correlation matrix, and the associated eigenspectrum.

Now, I have created an array that represents the eigenvectors row wise, and i would like to compute the transformation C*v^t, where c is the observation matrix and v^t is the element wise entries of the eigen vector transposed.

Now, since some of these matrices are pretty big-i'd like to be able to tell python which row of the eigenvector matrix to mulitply C by.  So far I have tried some of the numpy functions, but to no avail.

(for those of you wondering, i don't want to compute the matrix product of all the eigen vecotrs, i only need to multiply by a small subset of them-the ones associated with the largest eigenvalues)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To "slice" a vector of row `n` out of 2-dimensional array `A`, you use a syntax like `A[n]`.  If it's slicing columns you wanted instead, the syntax is `A[:,n]`.

For transformations with numpy arrays and vectors, the syntax is with matrix multiplication operator:

```
>>> A = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]])
>>> vs = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> A @ vs[0]  # this is a rotation of the first row of vs by A
array([-2,  1])
>>> A @ vs[1]  # this is a rotation of second row of vs by A
array([-4,  3])
```

*Note:* If you're on older python version (< 3.5), you might not have `@` available yet.  Then you'll have to use a [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) `np.dot(array, vector)` instead of the operator.

Comment: I'm running 3.6 so I think i should be okay!